# Python threads - number of arguments Error

Tags: python, multithreading

I am executing a command in a thread for almost 25k times like

```
if threaded is True:
                thread = Thread(target=threadedCommand, args=(cmd))
                thread.start()
                thread.join()  

def threadedCommand(command):
    if command is None:
        print 'can\'t execute threaded command'
        sys.exit(-1)
    print 'executing - %s'%(command)
    os.system(command)
```

and command is like

```
cp file dir
```

and what I see is

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 525, in __bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 477,
>   in run
>       self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs) TypeError:
>   threadedCommand() takes exactly 1 argument (52 given)
>
> ^CException in thread Thread-9377: Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 525, in
>   __bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 477,
>   in run
>       self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs) TypeError:
>   threadedCommand() takes exactly 1 argument (56 given)

Comment: `if threaded is True` is utterly pointless, fragile and verbose. Just use `if threaded`.

Comment: it comes a string though

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`args` must be a tuple. `(cmd)` is the same as `cmd`; you want a one-element tuple instead:

```
thread = Thread(target=threadedCommand, args=(cmd,))
#                                                ^
```

Comment: wonderful, Thanks a lot, that clears it out! appreciate your help